# Python Complicated Splitting of a String

Tags: python, string, split

Say that I have this string:

```
"hello":"noun":"a greeting";"hello":"verb":"the;action;of;greeting"
```

How can I make it so string.split(";") or string.split(":") will ignore any characters in quotation marks?

Thanks,
PM

Comment: `re.split` on `'"[;:]"'`?

Comment: What if that's what *inside* the quotes? It seems like this needs a tokenizer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't get a cleaner input than that, I'd recommend using a regular expression and creating a `list` of `tuple`s with `findall()`:

```
>>> import re
>>> mystring = '"hello":"noun":"a greeting";"hello":"verb":"the;action;of;greeting"'
>>> result = re.findall(r'"(.+?)":"(.+?)":"(.+?)"', mystring)
>>> for item in result:
...     print(*item)
...
hello noun a greeting
hello verb the;action;of;greeting
```

You can format the output with `str.format()`:

```
>>> for item in result:
...     print('{} - {}, {}'.format(*(part.replace(';', ' ') for part in item)))
...
hello - noun, a greeting
hello - verb, the action of greeting
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make it 100% clear if all strings are inside quoatation marks. Anyway, this should work. It doesn't remove the quotation marks around the string (you can do this afterwards if you want to).

```
In [20]: [x for x in re.split(r'(:|;|".*?")', s) if x not in [":",";",""]]
Out[20]:
['',
 '"hello"',
 '"noun"',
 '"a greeting"',
 '"hello"',
 '"verb"',
 '"the;action;of;greeting"']
```